# Why doesn't this jQuery focusout and change function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-focusout

This must be simple, but I can't see what is preventing this combonation .focusout and .change function from working.

I want the first input to copy to the second when the focus leaves the first input. No errors in the console. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fh8t6mm0/

The reason I want to use focusout is that the .change and .val function doesn't work reliably for some reason.

HTML:

```
<div id="focusoutdiv">

  <input class="fieldone" type="text">

  <input class="fieldtwo" type="text">

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#focusoutdiv').focusout(function() {
  $('.fieldone').change(function() {
    $('.fieldtwo').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use blur event to copy text from one textbox to other. Below code mightbe helpful for you

```
$('.fieldone').blur(function() {
    $('.fieldtwo').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much more efficient and is better than what I was trying to do with `$('.fieldtwo').val($(this).val());` on the overall DOM, which didn't always work.

Comment: Very glad to it works for you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `change` event inside `focusout` event. Because, they need to be defined separately to work as expected. Moreover in your code snippet, `change` event alone enough to achieve your requirement. Please refer the following example.

```js
$('.fieldone').change(function() {
  $('.fieldtwo').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="focusoutdiv">
  <input class="fieldone" type="text">
  <input class="fieldtwo" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I was doing before, but it didn't work reliably for some reason, so I wanted something to fire on a change directly with the inputs.

Comment: When .change and .val function doesn't work? Show us your fiddle example.